# $.getScript gives Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found some code online that helps me to provide widgets to my clients. My understanding of the full code below is that it first detects if jQuery is present otherwise loads it. As part of my widget I also want to ensure that fancybox is loaded because I am basically providing a button that onClicks loads an iframe in fancybox.

The particular area of interest is in which `.getScript` gives me an error `Unexpected token .`. I know that `jQuery` is already loaded because `.getJSON` below works.

Code:

```
    var fancyboxScript = widgetURL + "fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5");
    $.getScript(fancyboxScript);

    /******* Load HTML *******/
    var jsonp_url = widgetURL + "widgetCall.php?callback=?";
    $.getJSON(jsonp_url,'merchantID='+merchantID, function(data) {
      $('#widget-container').html(data.html);
    });
```

The full code is below:

```
(function() {
// Localize jQuery variable
var jQuery;
var widgetURL = "http://...mywidgetURL/...";
/******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.4.2') {
  var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
  script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
  script_tag.setAttribute("src",
    "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");
  if (script_tag.readyState) {
      script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
        if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
          scriptLoadHandler();
        }
      };
  } else {
      script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
  }

  // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
  (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] ||   document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
} else {
  // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
  jQuery = window.jQuery;
  main();
}

/******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
function scriptLoadHandler() {
  // Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
  // new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
  jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
  // Call our main function
  main(); 
}

/******** Our main function ********/
function main() {
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    /******* Load CSS *******/
    var css_link = $("<link>", { 
      rel: "stylesheet", 
      type: "text/css", 
      href: widgetURL + "myCSS.css" 
    });
    css_link.appendTo('head');

    /******* Load FANCYBOX *******/
    var fancy_link = $("<link>", { 
      rel: "stylesheet", 
      type: "text/css", 
      href: widgetURL + "fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5",
      media: "screen"
    });
    fancy_link.appendTo('head');

    var fancy2_link = $("<link>", { 
      rel: "stylesheet", 
      type: "text/css", 
      href: widgetURL + "fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7",
      media: "screen"
    });
    fancy2_link.appendTo('head');

    var fancyboxScript = widgetURL + "fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5");
    $.getScript(fancyboxScript);

    /******* Load HTML *******/
    var jsonp_url = widgetURL + "widgetCall.php?callback=?";
    $.getJSON(jsonp_url,'merchantID='+merchantID, function(data) {
      $('#widget-container').html(data.html);
    });
  });
}
})(); // We call our anonymous function immediately
```

Comment: but is there is being an `HTTP` request being *sent* to `fancyboxScript` location successfully with an `200` Code? What does the response header look like? It may of found *something* but doesn't like what it's seeing.

Comment: Are you sure that the url is well formed in this variable 'fancyboxScript' ?

Comment: I added a alert(fancyboxScript) to check the url and also got a syntax error `Unexpected token (`. But doing a `widgetURL + "fancybox/source/...."` worked in the previous CSS lines. It's strange why it doesnt work for this one.

Comment: oh my god it's because I had an additional `)` at the end of the url declaration. what an idiotic mistake! thanks for all the help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have made small mistake in your code

```
var fancyboxScript = widgetURL + "fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"); //closing round brackets is the issue
$.getScript(fancyboxScript);
```

you have added a closing round brackets   in the line above, hence the syntax error, just remove it and try, it should work as you intended.

Happy Coding:)

Answer (score 1):

well this must be one of the stupidest mistakes on SO. But I hope it saves someone some time in future.

Basically I had an additional `)` at the end of my `fancyboxScript` declaration.

`var fancyboxScript = widgetURL + "fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5");`

should have just been

`var fancyboxScript = widgetURL + "fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5";`